# How to turn on Haptic feedback on Galaxy Tab 4?

Tags: haptic-feedback, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

I think I have searched in all the sub-folders for a place to turn on Haptic feedback on my new Galaxy Tab 4?

I know it just barely came out, but for the life of me, I can't find anything remotely close to turning it on.

Using stock Samsung keyboard and SwiftKey. Neither has helped.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just purchased a Galaxy Tab 4 and the google keyboard when installed and configured to do so will provide a noticeable haptic feedback. The device does have a vibration motor but I can't find a setting to activate haptic feedback for the built in Samsung softkeys either (back and window change).

Comment: Welcome to  Android Enthusiasts! This is a question-and-answer site, not a forum. Please use the *Post answer* button only if you have a solution to the problem. If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://android.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: "The Google keyboard supports haptic feedback on this device" sounds like an answer to me.  He doesn't need to prove that the Samsung keyboard or Swiftkey don't support it, or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the Galaxy Tab 4 does have a vibrator motor, in that case it would be impossible to activate haptic feedback.